# Is reliable way to delete one item by zRemRangeByScore in Redis store?

Tags: redis

I have inserted json data to sorted set in Redis by score.
Score is `timestamp`.

Is it reliable way to delete item from sorted set by this score, if I specify `min,max` param as `timestamp`:

`$this->redis_php->zRemRangeByScore($key, $timestamp, $timestamp);`

So, if I have the semilar `$timestamp` for `max, min` it will be work with what range? I mean `<= =>` or `= =`

Answer (score 1):

It's safe unless there's more than an element in the sorted set with the same score: you're going to drop more than an element as the score range matches more than an element.

A sorted set is a *set* in terms of *element uniqueness* and this rule doesn't apply to element scores.